# How can I use \pgfmathsetmacro in a path?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath

I want to be able to draw line segments one after each other. They are predefined in their shape and hence I would like to have a macro to store them. Everything is fine, except that I am unable to call `\pgfmathsetmacro` while I am in a path and I would like to do that, is it possible?

This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\newcommand{\currentangle}{180}
\newcommand{\works}{arc (\currentangle:\currentangle - 30:5)}
\newcommand{\doesnotwork}{arc (\currentangle:\currentangle - 30:5) \pgfmathsetmacro\currentangle{\currentangle - 30}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[line width=4] (0,0) arc (180:90:5);
    
    \draw[line width=2,orange] (0,0) \works \works;
    
%   \draw[line width=2,orange] (0,0) \doesnotwork \doesnotwork;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, what I would like to do is to store the last angle in a command to have it available for the next segment, but using the `\doesnotwork` command leads to a crash with TikZ. Any ideas how to fix this or achieve the result in a different manner?

Comment: Wrap it in `\pgfextra{...}`.

Comment: That is to say `\pgfextra{\pgfmathsetmacro\currentangle{\currentangle - 30}}`

Comment: @HenriMenke thanks that was exactly what I was looking for, want to make it an answer?